# How to reattach a detached HEAD in GIT

Tags: git, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

(I can see there are many questions about this but I haven't found one that solves my exact problem).

I'm running gitlab-ci and when the runner checks out my code it does so as a detached head. Here is what I get when running a `git status` command in the runners directory.

```
git status
# HEAD detached at 847fe59
nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

What I need to do for what I am working on is to re-attach this head back to my develop branch and then `git pull` in the full repo for use in a docker container. I guess gitlab ci only checks out the last commit to save cloning down the full repo which is understandable.

In my `.gitlab-ci.yml` file I've tried the following...

```
- git checkout origin/$CI_BUILD_REF_NAME
- git pull
```

Which gives the following output in the console...

```
    $ git checkout $CI_BUILD_REF_NAME
    Switched to a new branch 'develop'
    Branch develop set up to track remote branch develop from origin.
$ git pull
You are not currently on a branch. Please specify which
branch you want to merge with. See git-pull(1) for details.
```

Is there an easy way to reattach the head? Most of the solutions I've seen deal with the fact a change has been committed onto the detached head however this isn't the case for me. I just want to get my full `develop` branch in my docker container with all of my git history.

Or if there is a way to stop gitlab ci from checking out the detached head that would also be great.

Comment: This isn't 100% clear.  Typically, CI systems check out a *specific* commit because there's no guarantee that the branch tip won't have moved on in the mean time (i.e. it ensures a deterministic code base).  With that in mind, why do you need to checkout `develop` as part of your CI build?

Comment: The main reason is so that I can run `gitversion` which automatically works out the `semver` etc based on the git repo. This doesn't work if I have a detached head.

Comment: Hmm.  Not that it's particularly helpful for me to say so, but that sounds like a bug/limitation in that tool - it ought to be able to compute a semver version from any commit.  Unless of course the issue here is that your CI is only doing a shallow clone?  (But that's different to it being a detached head.)

Comment: It is indeed a limitation. I guess the upshot is that it's impossible to re-attach the head.

Comment: @Remotec: you can use the `$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME` environment variable to get the current branch.

Answer (score 24):

A *detached HEAD* is simply a HEAD containing the raw hash ID of a commit.  As noted in the comments, it's generally pretty reasonable to use this for a build system, whether that's some sort of continuous integration or not: you might check out a specific commit by hash ID, or check out a tag name, but either way `HEAD` winds up containing the commit hash ID and is now guaranteed to be steady.

If you do want to have an "attached" (not-detached) HEAD, though, all you have to do in *Git* terms is to run `git checkout <branch-name>`.  This writes the name of the branch into `HEAD`, and now `HEAD` is attached to that branch.  This means that it's not `HEAD` at all, but rather the branch name, that determines which commit is current.  Anything that updates the branch name, changes the current commit.

Note that this property *only* applies to branch names, i.e., with names that live in the `refs/heads/` name-space.  The name `origin/branch` is typically shorthand for `refs/remotes/origin/branch`, which is not a branch name; it's a *remote-tracking name* (sometimes called a *remote-tracking branch*, which is a poor set of words because that sure *sounds* like "branch", doesn't it?).  Supplying any name to `git checkout` that *can* be resolved to a commit, but *is not* a branch name, results in a detached HEAD (if the checkout works at all, anyway).

If you want to have an attached HEAD, it must be attached to a branch name, i.e., a reference whose name starts with `refs/heads/`.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers already explained a lot of background, and I realize the question is old, but since people may land here in search of a solution here you go:

```yaml
job:
  script:
    - git switch $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME #returning to branch from detached HEAD
    - <your CI script>
  variables:
    GIT_DEPTH: 0
    GIT_STRATEGY: clone
```

Note:

1. You might as well use `before_script:` if you intend to use this as a template
2. You might as well use `git checkout` over `switch`. `checkout`, however, can deal with branches and paths, so `switch` is a bit more targeted.
3. `GIT_STRATEGY: clone` and `GIT_DEPTH: 0` tell GitLab to create a full clone of the repo, including all branches and commits. Without that, the branch won't be known to git.  `GIT_DEPTH: 0` means that all commits will be cloned. As far as I know, this could safely be set to `100`, for example.

Answer (score -2):

This worked for me

Command:

`git checkout FETCH_HEAD`

Output:

```
Previous HEAD position was 3cf5de5... Initial commit
HEAD is now at 600ea51... Sample Git Demo
```

Comment: `FETCH_HEAD ` didn't work, I got this: `$ git checkout FETCH_HEAD
error: pathspec 'FETCH_HEAD' did not match any file(s) known to git.
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1`

Comment: Enter `git fetch` first and then again try with `git checkout FETCH_HEAD`

Comment: This command took me to another branch that was ahead of mine

Answer (score -2):

i had about the same  situation:
you can always create a new branch and merge it with  the branch you  where detached from