# Why am I getting a detached HEAD during gitlab/git merge-request/merge?

Tags: git, merge, gitlab, git-detached-head

Firstly like to mention that I have tried a few things from prior questions but none of them fit my scenario.

1. [This does not somehow "register" as a merge in gitlab.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5772192/how-can-i-reconcile-detached-head-with-master-origin) I concluded this because when I try to delete the branch after merge, git threw a warning. Of course I can force delete the branch but I would prefer to keep the merge history clean.
2. [This answer, afai understand, seems to be for sub repositories/modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48316728/how-to-prevent-detached-head-when-merging) which is not my setup here.
3. [Did not experiment with it to avoid any possible further inconsistency.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47154114/how-to-reattach-a-detached-head-in-git)

This is the scenario:

I have a repository in GitLab and I am trying to resolve a Merge Request i.e. merging the associated branch of the MR to master. After committing and pushing all the changes to the MR branch `19-some-function` , I followed the instructions in Gitlab [4] to manually `merge` which results in a `detached HEAD` state.

```
$ git fetch origin

$ git checkout -b 19-some-function origin/19-some-function
fatal: A branch named '19-some-function' already exists.

$ git checkout origin/master
Note: switching to 'origin/master'.

You are in 'detached HEAD' state. You can look around, make experimental 
[truncated]

$ git merge --no-ff 19-some-function
Merge made by the 'recursive' strategy.
 package-lock.json                                  |  55 +++++++
 package.json                                       |   1 +
 src/Common/Constants.js                            |   2 +-
 src/Common/utils.js                                |  23 +++
```

(as opposed to doing it by Gitlab MR page UI: "resolve WIP" > "Merge" by clicking the button which to be frank I am not sure what it does BHS. However must add, when I did use the UI, I did not get a detached HEAD) I am the only developer and there is no separate reviewer yet, so I do not know if Step 1 & 2 in the instructions are redundant (it attempts to create the MR branch. which makes sense for a reviewer but as a developer of the feature I already have the branch so `git` throws an error, seen above therefore did not make sense to run `git fetch origin` again before `checkout`).

How do I resolve this `detached HEAD` such that it is recorded as the merge of `19-some-function` with `master`? Will question/answer (2) above help?

[4] MR branch is `19-some-function`

```
Check out, review, and merge locally
×
Step 1. Fetch and check out the branch for this merge request
  git fetch origin
  git checkout -b 19-some-function origin/19-some-function

Step 2. Review the changes locally

Step 3. Merge the branch and fix any conflicts that come up
  git fetch origin
  git checkout origin/master
  git merge --no-ff 19-some-function

Step 4. Push the result of the merge to GitLab
  git push origin master
```

Comment: I don't know who wrote those instructions, but they're just wrong. It's not clear why they want you to create a local branch in step 1 (the only things that really matter are the commits) but the biggest problem is that step 3's middle command *guarantees* a detached HEAD, which makes step 4 pointless as written. Perhaps they meant you should `git checkout master`, but if so, that needs more attention; perhaps they meant that in step 4, you should use `HEAD:master`; one way or another, these instructions are wrong.

Comment: ok.. probably worth letting Gitlab know this then. anyhow, how do i undo this and do a proper merge? Can I still do this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5601931/what-is-the-best-and-safest-way-to-merge-a-git-branch-into-master

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You set yourself on *detached HEAD* state when you ask to checkout **origin/master**. You are not checking out the *local* branch master, so you have to be put on *detached HEAD*. But that is ok. You could then merge the PR branch you want and then push to origin/master if you wanted to:

```
git push origin HEAD:master
```

Comment: great, thanks! this worked and marked it as a proper merge